# Including tsquery result in partitioned table vs. materialized view

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to build a table optimized for rapid querying for full text search.

I have followed this guide [Postgres Full Text Search Is Good Enough](http://rachbelaid.com/postgres-full-text-search-is-good-enough/) and created a materialized view, with a column that contains the result of the following:

```
(setweight(to_tsvector(v.text_content), 'A'::"char") || setweight(to_tsvector(v.category_name), 'C'::"char") AS document
```

The problem I am having is that the search results need to be up to date shortly after any modifications. This means the materialized view will need to be frequently updated (likely multiple times per minute) for a table that will ultimately have 100s of millions to billions of rows.

This seems like a poor design, so what I am wondering, is would it be better to create a partitioned table with the tsvector result as a regular column? That way any modifications to a single record don't require a refresh of the materialized view.

Is this a better choice?

Table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE public.text_records
(
id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('id_seq'::regclass),
user_id integer NOT NULL,
date timestamp with time zone NOT NULL DEFAULT now(),
text_content jsonb,
category_id integer NOT NULL
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a trigger or a GENERATED column or a functional index to compute  the tsvector on the fly.